# java program unable to find jar file in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

I have added two jar files to module settings of a project in intellij, when i run my project the java class doesn't find the jar file, I can see the jars under external libraries, what is the issue? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

```
Steps for adding external jars in IntelliJ IDEA:

Click File from File menu
Project Structure (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X)
Select Modules at the left panel
Dependencies tab
'+' → JARs or directories
```

Comment: added in the same way and i can see them under external libraries folder, But when i run the code i get: package com.tableausoftware.DataExtract does not exist @Abhishek Singh